# Deleting forward linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list, forward-list

There are two known ways (only two ?) to delete forward linked list

1. One way is the recursive function which is inefficient and would give stack overflow if the list is too large
2. Another way (the efficient) is a function that iterates and deletes nodes like this:

   ```
   class Forward_list {
   public:
      // Constructor...

      ~Forward_list() { if(head) destroy(); }

      void destroy() {
           node* prev = nullptr;
           while (head) {
               prev = head;
               head = head->next;
               delete prev;
           }
       }

       // functions...
   private:
       // data members...
       node* head;
   };
   ```

Now what about doing it this way:

```
class Forward_list {
public:
    // Constructor...

    ~Forward_list() { if(head) delete this->head; }

    // functions...
private:
    struct node {
        ~node() { delete this->next; } // <- this way
        type data;
        node* next;
    };
    node* head;
    // data members...
};
```

I tested it and it works fine ... I find this way cleaner but not sure if there would be side effects ?

Comment: What if you want to delete just one node?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: You unlink it from the list first, which sets `node->next` to `nullptr` making the `delete this->next` a no-op.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your solution is technically correct, the only problem I can think of is you can't delete one node without deleting all the nodes that follow.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ  this answer appeared first to me ... I didnt ignore you and I +1 you anyway

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> ~node() { delete this->next; } // <- this way
> ```
>
> I find this way cleaner but not sure if there would be side effects ?

Well, the *"side effect"* will be, that you can't remove any nodes from the list, without deleting the whole rest of the list, since `~node()` is called recursively there.

That's probably not what you want to do.

Answer (score 2):

Since it wasn't mentioned before: when using

```
delete this->next;
```

note that the *destructor* gets invoked recursively, i.e., the approach of `delete`ing the next node in the destructor is equivalent to the recursive approach of `delete`ing a list. The recursion is just not as direct and obvious.